# python selenium error: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping Banggood, the problem is that driver open just first link and then doesn't go to next link of links list( next product )

and get this error in line 24

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

but i tried to print links out of loop i got all of the

```
print( links[0].get_attribute('href') )
print( links[2].get_attribute('href') )
```

main code :

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver #THIS IS MAIN SCRIPT

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Compu City\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe')#DRIVER LOCATION
driver.get('https://usa.banggood.com/Deals_Electronics.html#dealscategories2')#DRIVER LOCATION
driver.implicitly_wait(30)


links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('body > div.flashdeals-container.fixed > div.main > div.product-list.cf > ul > li > a.products_name.exclick')
#links has 25 link
product=0
while product <= len(links):

    driver.get(links[product].get_attribute('href'))


    try:# TITLE
        title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#centerCtrl > div.title_hd > h2 > strong')
        print(title.text)
    except:
        print('no title')

    try:# NEW PRICE
        new_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#centerCtrl > div.itemBox > div.item_price_box > div.item_now_price')
        print(new_price.text)
    except:
        print('no new price')

    try:# OLD PRICE
        old_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#centerCtrl > div.itemBox > div.item_price_box > div.item_old_price')
        print(old_price.text)
    except:
        print('no old price')

    try:#image
        image = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#landingImage').get_attribute('src')
        print(image)
    except:
        print('no image')
    product +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that

```
v=[]
for x in links:
    #driver.get(links[1].get_attribute('href'))
    print(v.append(x.get_attribute('href')))

print(len(v))
driver.get(v[1])
time.sleep(10)
driver.get(v[2])
product=0
while product <= len(v):

    driver.get(v[product])
    product +=1
```